# organizing blueprint specific configuration in Flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

currently I'm trying to create an internal app for my company, which bundles different use cases into one app. This also means that I may have different configurations for each use case.

I decided to organize my Flask app with Blueprints, SQL statements are triggered with SQLAlchemy, but what I'm not able to figure out is how to use a different database for each Blueprint to pass it to SQLAlchemy. Or is it the best way to use this with multiple binds in one configuration?

Please share your experiences.

Many thanks in advance, regards, Thomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I played around a little bit and found a workable solution for me. I use binds for blueprint specific databases.

Here's how it works (for me), just if anyone might be interested in or struggeling with the same question.

1. add your database configuration in some `./app/config.py` script

```py
class Config():

    #Secret key
    SECRET_KEY = 'you_never_know'


    SQLALCHEMY_BINDS = {
        'database': 'mysql+mysqlconnector://user:password@localhost/database'
    }
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False
```

2. in your `./app/__init__.py` you do the following:

```
from flask import Flask
from .config import Config

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Config)

with app.app_context():
    from .somewhat_app import bp as somewhat_bp
    app.register_blueprint(somewhat_bp)
```

3. `./app//somewhat_app/__init__.py`:

```
from flask import Blueprint

bp = Blueprint('somewhat', __name__, url_prefix='/somewhat')

from . import somewhat
```

4. `./app/somewhat_app/somewhat.py`:

```
from . import bp
from flask import (
    render_template, request, url_for, jsonify, make_response
)
from flask import current_app as app

from .model import MyTable

@bp.route('/')
def index():
    resp = MyTable.query.limit(20).all()
    return render_template('somewhat/index.html', resp=resp)
```

5. `./app/somewhat_app/model.py`:

```
from flask import current_app as app
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
db.reflect(bind='database')

class MyTable(db.Model):
    __bind_key__ = 'database'
    __table__ = db.metadata.tables['mytable']
```